# Cache image to disk

Tags: image, file, caching, process, xamarin

I am coding a Xamarin application and am retrieving images off the web and loading them into a GridView. Rather than downloading an image each time, I wish to speed this process up. I gather I need to cache the images.

Is caching basically just saving the image to a file, and when wanting to display the image, retrieve the image from file rather than from the web?

Is the following correct:

1. Check if the local file exists
2. Check if the local file has the same size of the web file
3. If the size is different, get and save the new file off the web and then load the new file
4. If the size is the same, load the local saved file

Is the process as simple as that? Is there a design pattern or tutorial written that can explain everything that needs to be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's pretty much it. However I would compare image's date, not size (HTTP is well adjusted for this). Also pay attention to synchronization if you want to make it threadsafe.

Comment: I am thinking to use some async loading code from a user resource. Do you recommend any that I should expressly look into? I am currently looking at ImageLoader.

Comment: If you are talking about Android resources, why don't you use Android resource mechanism? And if it isn't smooth enough, fire it in a Task to load image from resource and then assign it in UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to effectively cache images, the server you're downloading the images from needs to support a protocol to assist you with caching. One of the most commonly accepted standard protocols for web cache is `ETag`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag

Here's how it works:

1) You request an image from http://someurl.com/image.jpg

2) The server responds with the image, and in the response headers, there will be a `ETag` value of some identifier: *abc123*

3) You save the image to local storage as well as the ETag value.

4) The next time you request the image from that same URL, you pass a new header; `If-None-Match` with the ETag value you saved *abc123*

5) If the image or content hasn't changed, then the server will respond with status code `304 Not Modified`, and you just display the image you saved locally. If the image has changed, the server will respond with the status code 200 and a new ETag value and you download the image as your normally would replacing your cached copy.

Comment: HTTP also has additional headers like 'Expires' and 'Max-Age' that allow the client to use a cached image for a period of time without even doing a conditional fetch as Mike outlines in steps 4 and 5 above.